# Autocomplete field using external API with Salesforce

Tags: javascript, api, cross-domain, salesforce, apex-code

Is it possible to create an autocompleted field using data from an external (non Salesforce) REST/JSON API?

I guess that if I try to do it I'll run in some same-origin policy problems. So maybe using an APEX class acting as proxy between my JS and my API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the  [sforce.connection.remoteFunction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/Content/sforce_api_ajax_queryresultiterator.htm) funciton from the ajax tookit to get the data from external servers. You will not get the same-orign policy error. And then you could use the [jQuery's autocomplete](http://jungleeforce.wordpress.com/2013/05/05/using-jquerys-autocomplete-in-salesforce-part-2/) plugin to achieve the auto-complete functionality